# The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect

Tags: nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 in a Intel Ivy Bridge with integrated graphics and NVidia GPU with Optimus tech, however i cant manage it to work properly. I have already passed by the solution of bumblebee project, however iam got the following message when try to run anything with nvidia card( e.g. with `optirun firefox`):

```
[ERROR]The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect.
[ERROR]Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?
```

Since the nvidia card is not working properly, some softwares like Scilab, that make use of X11 system for graphic handling and plotting, wont work too.

my bios has no option concerning graphics card and the log of daemon returned:

```
Jul 5 16:10:51 humannoise-W251ESQ-W270ESQ bumblebeed[980]: Module 'nvidia' is not found. 
Jul 5 16:10:51 humannoise-W251ESQ-W270ESQ kernel: [ 17.943272] init: bumblebeed main process (980) terminated with status 1 
Jul 5 16:10:51 humannoise-W251ESQ-W270ESQ kernel: [ 17.943288] init: bumblebeed main process ended, respawning 
Jul 5 16:10:51 humannoise-W251ESQ-W270ESQ bumblebeed[1026]: Module 'nvidia' is not found.
```

The `lspci -nn | grep '\[030[02]\]:'` returned:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:0de9] (rev a1)
```

Ok, for the command `dpkg -l | grep '^ii' | grep nvidia` i got :

```
ii  bumblebee-nvidia                       3.0-2~preciseppa1                         nVidia Optimus support using the proprietary NVIDIA driver
ii  nvidia-current                         302.17-0ubuntu1~precise~xup1            NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
ii  nvidia-current-updates                 295.49-0ubuntu0.1                       NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
ii  nvidia-settings                        302.17-0ubuntu1~precise~xup3            Tool of configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-settings-updates                295.33-0ubuntu1                         Tool of configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

After full reinstallation, including the remove of any previous nvidia drive, `lsmod | grep -E 'nvidia|nouveau'` returned:

```
nvidia              10888310  46
```

dmesg | grep -C3 -E 'nouveau|NVRM' returned things like:

```
[ 1875.607283] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[ 1875.607289] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[ 1875.607293] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:01:00.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
[ 1875.607363] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  302.17  Tue Jun 12 16:03:22 PDT 2012
[ 1884.830035] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: PCI INT A disabled
[ 1884.832058] bbswitch: disabling discrete graphics
[ 1884.832960] bbswitch: Result of Optimus _DSM call: 09000019
```

Some programs, like Scilab, are now working fine under optirun(e.g. `>optirun scilab`) call.

Comment: you need to restart the system.

Comment: How you get the Bios information? which command line You used?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error "Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?" means that the Bumblebee daemon refused/ failed to start.

In your case, "Module 'nvidia' is not found.". This means that the Nvidia kernel driver has not properly been installed. Make sure that you install the `linux-headers-generic` package and reinstall the nvidia package:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-current
```

---

It could also occur if your system is not detected as an Optimus laptop which has two graphics card, an Intel and a Nvidia one. Check your `/var/log/syslog` file for messages from "bumblebeed" (the Bumblebee daemon):

```
grep bumblebeed /var/log/syslog
```

If the message is *No nVidia graphics card found, quitting.*, then your laptop has no Nvidia chip or it is disabled in BIOS. The message *No Optimus system detected, quitting.* is shown when the Intel graphics card cannot be found. In either case, check the BIOS settings for an "Optimus mode / integrated only / discrete only" option (or: "detect Optimus).

The output of the command `lspci -nn | grep '\[030[02]\]:` should look like:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: **Intel Corporation** Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 02)
>   01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: **NVIDIA Corporation** GF108 [GeForce GT 425M] [10de:0df0] (rev ff)

Comment: @Humannoise Strange, installing `bumblebee` should also pull the nvidia-current package. What does `dmesg | grep -C3 -E 'nouveau|NVRM'` and `lsmod | grep -E 'nvidia|nouveau'` yield? You can add it to your question.

Comment: empty return to nouveau commands

Comment: Can you add `dpkg -l | grep '^ii' | grep nvidia` to your question? You did not add `lsmod | grep ...` to your question, was it empty?

Comment: yes it was empty, both commands

Comment: Did you actually install Bumblebee as described at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee?

Comment: I purged the previous installation and removed all nvidia drivers, then i re-installed as it's said in the link. Now everything is going well, iam very thankfull, updating my question...

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue after upgrading some of my packages. It seems the problem was caused by the Nvidia kernel module being renamed from "nvidia" to "nvidia_current".

If you have the `nvidia-current` package installed, you can fix the issue by editing `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` and setting the following values:

```
...
[bumblebeed]
Driver=nvidia
...
[driver-nvidia]
KernelDriver=nvidia_current
Module=nvidia
...
```

Then restart bumblebee:

```
sudo service bumblebeed restart
```

And test:

```
optirun glxgears
```

References:

- https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/238
- https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/330

Answer (score 1):

**Symptoms**

If get this errors with `optirun playonlinux` or `optirun -b playonlinux` :

```
[ERROR]The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect.
[ERROR]Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?
```

Then your bumbleblee conf file is not be up-to-date.

**Auto correction of the bumblebee conf file**

You can copy/past theses commands in a terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the old nvidia version used by the conf file
oldNvidiaVersion=`cat /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf |grep "KernelDriver=nvidia" | cut -d- -f2`

# Get the current nvidia version
nvidiaVersion=`find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name 'nvidia_???.ko*' | cut -d_ -f2 |cut -d. -f1`
echo "nvidiaVersion : $oldNvidiaVersion => $nvidiaVersion"

# Test the update the Bumblebee conf file
# cat /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf | sed "s/$oldNvidiaVersion/$nvidiaVersion/g"

# Update the Bumblebee conf file
echo "Update /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf ..."
sudo sed -i "s/$oldNvidiaVersion/$nvidiaVersion/g" /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
echo done.

# Restart bumblebeed deamon
sudo systemctl restart bumblebeed.service
```

**Optional** : If you often update your nvidia drivers, you can save this commands in a file `bumbleble_update_conf.sh`, then `chmmod +x bumbleble_update_conf.sh` and execute it `./bumbleble_update_conf.sh`

Now `optirun playonlinux` or `optirun -b playonlinux` should work!