# how to fix "The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path was incorrect"?

Tags: 12.10, dell, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, xps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NVidia with Optimus conflicting in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159767/nvidia-with-optimus-conflicting-in-ubuntu-12-04)

I just bought a new Dell XPS 14 Ultrabook which comes with a NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M. So, following some indications that I found in the documentation available online I add the bumblebee ppa and installed bumblebee and nvidia-bumblebee.

But when I tried to use the nvidia card to run something i got this error:

```
optirun -vv firefox
[  476.380739] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[  476.381430] [INFO]Configured driver: nvidia
[  476.381498] [ERROR]The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect.
[  476.381513] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
[  476.381534] [ERROR]Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?
```

Here are some of the configuration files:

/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf

```
# Configuration file for Bumblebee. Values should **not** be put between quotes

## Server options. Any change made in this section will need a server restart
# to take effect.
[bumblebeed]
# The secondary Xorg server DISPLAY number
VirtualDisplay=:8
# Should the unused Xorg server be kept running? Set this to true if waiting
# for X to be ready is too long and don't need power management at all.
KeepUnusedXServer=false
# The name of the Bumbleblee server group name (GID name)
ServerGroup=bumblebee
# Card power state at exit. Set to false if the card shoud be ON when Bumblebee
# server exits.
TurnCardOffAtExit=false
# The default behavior of '-f' option on optirun. If set to "true", '-f' will
# be ignored.
NoEcoModeOverride=false
# The Driver used by Bumblebee server. If this value is not set (or empty),
# auto-detection is performed. The available drivers are nvidia and nouveau
# (See also the driver-specific sections below)
Driver=nvidia

## Client options. Will take effect on the next optirun executed.
[optirun]
# The method used for VirtualGL to transport frames between X servers.
# Possible values are proxy, jpeg, rgb, xv and yuv.
VGLTransport=proxy
# Should the program run under optirun even if Bumblebee server or nvidia card
# is not available?
AllowFallbackToIGC=false


# Driver-specific settings are grouped under [driver-NAME]. The sections are
# parsed if the Driver setting in [bumblebeed] is set to NAME (or if auto-
# detection resolves to NAME).
# PMMethod: method to use for saving power by disabling the nvidia card, valid
# values are: auto - automatically detect which PM method to use
#         bbswitch - new in BB 3, recommended if available
#       switcheroo - vga_switcheroo method, use at your own risk
#             none - disable PM completely
# https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Comparison-of-PM-methods

## Section with nvidia driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nvidia
[driver-nvidia]
# Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset
KernelDriver=nvidia-current
Module=nvidia
PMMethod=auto
# colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/lib32/nvidia-current
# comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the
# default Xorg modules path
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

## Section with nouveau driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nouveau
[driver-nouveau]
KernelDriver=nouveau
PMMethod=auto
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau
```

/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "Layout0"
    Option "AutoAddDevices" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device1"
    Driver "nvidia"
    VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Option "NoLogo" "true"
    Option "UseEDID" "false"
    Option "ConnectedMonitor" "DFP"
EndSection
```

And some additional information

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia

ii  bumblebee-nvidia                          3.0.1-3~quantalppa1                       amd64        nVidia Optimus support using the proprietary NVIDIA driver
ii  nvidia-current                            304.51.really.304.43-0ubuntu1             amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
rc  nvidia-current-updates                    304.51-0ubuntu1                           amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
ii  nvidia-settings                           304.51-0ubuntu2                           amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

I removed the nvidia-current-updates because unity was not able to start with it installed.

By the way, I'm using the latest version of 64 bit ubuntu (12.10); and I have tried reinstalling bumblebee like 3 times.

Can you help me fixing this error? Is there other information you might need in order to help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It could help you bro , it worked for me ;) 
http://www.ivegotavirus.com/how-to-fix-bumblebee-on-ubuntu-12-10/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.