# module nvidia is not found error - bumblebee

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee

today I've installed bumblebee with nvidia-current, but when I check if bumblebee is  ok (bumblebee-config),I can read this

> [ERROR] Module "nvidia" is not found.

What can I do?

Thanks you in advance

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/159767/nvidia-with-optimus-conflicting-in-ubuntu-12-04 http://askubuntu.com/questions/289459/nvidia-drivers-installed-but-not-used The 2nd one seems better.

Comment: Now i get this error:
>ERROR daemon already running